# Out of KCl, CaCl2, MgCl2, NaCl, which causes the greatest corrosion rate of iron and why?

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, solutions, periodic-trends, salt

I know that salts act as an electrolyte in a redox process and rusting of iron, where iron loses electrons and oxidizes, and oxygen gains electrons and reduces. I did an experiment with KCl, NaCl, MgCl2 and CaCl2 salts dissolved in water, then dipped iron nails in the separate solutions to see which nail would rust more over a period of time. My result was MgCl2>CaCl2>KCl>NaCl. For my analysis I'm looking for an explanation as to why MgCl2 solution had the most rust, the CaCl2 the second most ect. I wondered about periodic trends and how I could look at electron affinity to see which salt could accept electrons the easiest, but I'm not sure if it's right. I just want help on this chemical process and an in depth explanation for my results. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice to know how you pre-treated surface of the nails, what steel they are made of, what temperature and concentrations of the salts were used, and how you estimated rusting quantitatively.

Comment: I guess it all boils down to "how much chloride".